# Loading JSON with Group in canvas with fabric.js

Tags: json, fabricjs

I want to save the objects of the canvas and put them to JSON, but when I do it with a Group, I get the following error:

> o.setCoords is not a function in all.js (Zeile 10403), while executing _calcBound() Function on the Rect-Object.

Here my test code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("pitch_600");
    var group = new fabric.Group();
    var rect = new fabric.Rect({ 
        width: 100, 
        height: 200, 
        left: 10, 
        top: 50, 
        fill: 'black' 
    });

    group.add(rect);
    canvas.add(group);

    var saved = JSON.stringify(canvas.toDatalessJSON());
    canvas.clear();
    console.debug(saved);
    canvas.loadFromJSON(saved);
});
</script>

<canvas id="pitch_600" width="650px" height="454px"></canvas>
```

On http://tacticboards.xaga.de/test.html You can find a online demo of it.
I hope you can help.